# ThreeJS MeshPhongMaterial renders black (MeshLambertMaterial renders correctly)

Tags: three.js

Is there a solution to this problem? If I change my materialdefinition from MeshPhone to MeshLambert, everything works as expected, otherwise, it won't (but only on some computers, my dev machine works just fine).

http://peppr-configurator.herokuapp.com/#/

The function 'loadDefaultMaterialForObject' in the 'MaterialConfService' is where this gets loaded.

```
var threeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    specular: material.properties.specular,
    emissive: material.properties.emissive,
    shininess: material.properties.shininess,
});
```

Swapping out the 'MeshPhongMaterial' for a 'MeshLambertMaterial' works, but I need the phong for highlights.

Does anybody have a clue what might be going on here?

Comment: and how do you expect us to debug minified code?

Comment: My apologies. I've uploaded a version with the unminified source code (did put it all in one file). In the 'MaterialConfService' on line 560 it builds up the material. If I swap out 'MeshPhongMaterial' for 'MeshLambertMaterial', everything works as expected. Now, everything renders black.

Comment: Does it give any error on the machines where it renders black?

Comment: There is an error in the render loop, suggesting Three.ShadowMapPlugin has an issue with the pointlight setup. I cannot stack trace it though because opening the debugger crashes chrome; The render loop is hitting this error at every frame. Relatedly, a meshlambert and meshphong materials that appear black are not being lit with a light. They need a functioning light to calculate their visual effects. It is possible some browsers cannot cope with observed error as well as other browsers. I would switch to a directional light and see if the problem persists. A fiddle would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

couldn't reproduce the error, but I would start here:

Try commenting out light.castShadow = true:

```
  var pLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,0.25);
  //pLight.castShadow = true;
  pLight.position.set(50,100,50);
  _this.scene.add(pLight);

  var pLight02 = new THREE.PointLight(0xefeeeee,0.2);
  //pLight02.castShadow = true;
  pLight02.position.set(-50,100,50);
  _this.scene.add(pLight02);

  var pLight03 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,0.2);
  //pLight03.castShadow = true;
  pLight03.position.set(0,75,-75);
  _this.scene.add(pLight03);
```

THREE.PointLight can't cast shadows and causes errors

for more info see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1192